# random percentage that fluctuates javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to pick a random number based on a percentage. 0-5

```
0 - 25% (25/100)
1 - 25% (25/100)
2 - 20% (20/100)
3 - 15% (15/100)
4 - 10% (10/100)
5 - 5%  (5/100)
```

But, sometimes one or more of those values will need to be omitted from the picking. So you could encounter something like this

```
0 - 25% (25/65)
2 - 20% (20/65)
3 - 15% (15/65)
5 - 5%  (5/65)
```

Which means that the percentage has to scale with the other numbers there.

I thought I could use a random function to do something like this

```
var1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

//0 - 25% random(1-25)
//1 - 25% random(26-50)
//2 - 20% random(51-70)
//3 - 15% random(71-85)
//4 - 10% random(86-95)
//5 - 5%  random(96-100)

if(var1 <= 25){
  var2 = 0;
}else if(var1 <= 50){
  var2 = 1;
}else if(var1 <= 70){
  var2 = 2;
}else if(var1 <= 85){
  var2 = 3;
}else if(var1 <= 95){
  var2 = 4;
}else if(var1 <= 100){
  var2 = 5;
}else{
  // error
}
```

But I ran into a problem when one or more of the variables (0-5) is omitted. It is possible to setup a bunch of if/else statements but it's not a very practical solution.

Does anybody know a better way I could possibly do this?

Also, if you're unsure of what my question is, please say so. I will try to be more specific and clear on my intentions.

Comment: Rather than hardcoding the % values (`25`, `50`, .. up to `100`) consider storing them dynamically and summing them as appropriate. That would make it fairly trivial to model after the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it is exactly what you want. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/pn0vt2ew/)

```
function RangeArray(diffs) {
    this.diffs = diffs;
}

// Omit range by index
RangeArray.prototype.omitAt = function(index) {
    var arr = this.diffs;

    // move value to the next item in array
    arr[index + 1] += arr[index];
    arr[index] = 0;
}

// Find index of range for value
RangeArray.prototype.indexOf = function(value) {
    var arr = this.diffs;
    var sum = 0;

    for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; ++index) {
        sum += arr[index];
        if (value < sum) {
            return index;
        }            
    }

    return -1;
}

// ------- tests ----------

// array of ranges created using your percentage steps
var ranges = new RangeArray([25,25,20,15,10,5]);

// your random values
var values = [1, 26, 51, 70, 86, 99];

// test resutls: indexes of ranges for values
var indexes;

console.log('ranges: 1-25, 26-50, 51-70, 71-85, 86-95, 96-100');
console.log('random values: ' + values.join(', '));

// for your random values indexOf should return 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 accordingly
indexes = values.map(function(x) { return ranges.indexOf(x); });
console.log('test 1 results: ' + indexes.join(', '));

// omit range at index 1 and 4
ranges.omitAt(1);
ranges.omitAt(4);

// for your random values indexOf should return 0, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5 accordingly
indexes = values.map(function(x) { return ranges.indexOf(x); });
console.log('test 2 results: ' + indexes.join(', '));
```

Answer (score 1):

You store your ranges in an **array** with a the percentage of each block then you can check them. Be sure that your array sums up to 100.

You can use a simple loop.

```
var1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
var2 =0;
results = [25,25,20,15,10,5];

total = 0;
for (i = 0;i <results.length; i++ ) {
    total += results[i];
    if (var1 < total) {
        var2 = i;
        break;
    }            
}
console.log(var1)
console.log(var2)
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/auo6nc7p/

So in the array above the first item has 25% probablility, the second 25% and so on. You can then remove the element from the array if you do not want them to be picked up.

Is that answering your question ?

Comment: close. If, for example, 2 or 5 is removed, then their corresponding percentage must also be removed (20% & 5%) but it should still return numbers (0,1,3,4). That is pretty interesting though, maybe I could modify it.

Comment: I guess than a bit more complex data structure should be used instead of a plain array.